# how can i solve java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, android

Hi I am using am developing android application that uses a custom list view, but I keep getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error. Yet I cant find any errors in my code where could I have gone wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv_event;

    List<HashMap<String, String>> alist;

    String[] event_name = { "The Kampala City Festival",
            "The Awakening (Lantern Meet of Poets Recital)" };
    int[] event_img = { R.drawable.kla_festival, R.drawable.city_rooming };
    String[] event_date = { "October 6th, 2013", "October 4th, 2013" };
    String[] event_venue = { "Watoto Church, Central", "National Theatre" };
    String[] event_time = { "11:30 am", "07:00 pm" };
    String[] event_info = { "The #KampalaCityFestival will on Sunday 6th October",
             "From the creators of Broken Voices of the Revolution "
             };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUI();
        setEventList();
    }

    private void setEventList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            alist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hm.put("event_picture", Integer.toString(event_img[i]));
                hm.put("event_name", event_name[i]);
                hm.put("event_date", event_date[i]);
                hm.put("event_venue", event_venue[i]);
                hm.put("event_time", event_time[i]);
                hm.put("event_info", event_info[i]);
                alist.add(hm);
            }

            // from
            String[] from = { "event_picture", "event_name", "event_date",
                    "event_venue", "event_time", "event_info" };
            // to
            int[] to = { R.id.img_view_event, R.id.tv_event_name, R.id.tv_date,
                    R.id.tv_event_place, R.id.tv_time, R.id.tv_event_info };

            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    alist, R.layout.lv_custom, from, to);

            lv_event.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void setUI() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lv_event = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_event);
    }
```

Comment: Size of

String[] event_name = { "The Kampala City Festival",
        "The Awakening (Lantern Meet of Poets Recital)" };
is only 2. So you can use only 0 and 1 index to get elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over arrays three times expecting three elements in each array.

But here you have defined only two values, for example:

```
String[] event_name = { "The Kampala City Festival",
        "The Awakening (Lantern Meet of Poets Recital)" };
```

and that might be the reason you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

So try changing `i < 3` to `i < 2`, if you want to have only 2 elements in the array or add one element to arrays that have only 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at all your arrays, you `for` needs a change

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // since there are only 2 elements in all your arrays.
```

Index is 0-based for the arrays. Therefore, 2 elements in the array means, you have elements at arr[0] and arr[1]. arr[2] will give you the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays have a length of 2, not 3.

Change your for from

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
```

-

```
array[0]; // first element
array[1]; // second element
array[2]; // out of bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrays declared at the beginning of the class only contain two elements.  Yet the loop will attempt to access a third element.  Simply adjust the guard in the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hm.put("event_picture", Integer.toString(event_img[i]));
    hm.put("event_name", event_name[i]);
    hm.put("event_date", event_date[i]);
    hm.put("event_venue", event_venue[i]);
    hm.put("event_time", event_time[i]);
    hm.put("event_info", event_info[i]);
    alist.add(hm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("event_picture", Integer.toString(event_img[i]));
        hm.put("event_name", event_name[i]);
        hm.put("event_date", event_date[i]);
        hm.put("event_venue", event_venue[i]);
        hm.put("event_time", event_time[i]);
        hm.put("event_info", event_info[i]);
        alist.add(hm);
  }
```

Change this one instead of your code

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("event_picture", Integer.toString(event_img[i]));
        hm.put("event_name", event_name[i]);
        hm.put("event_date", event_date[i]);
        hm.put("event_venue", event_venue[i]);
        hm.put("event_time", event_time[i]);
        hm.put("event_info", event_info[i]);
        alist.add(hm);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

just change

`for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)`

or

`for (int i = 0; i < event_name.length; i++)` that's it

Comment: when you have only two values in array then why you give 3 time loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to avoid this kind of exception.

**new foreach:**

```
for (Object anObject : objectArray) {
    anObject.doStuff();
}
```

**old foreach:**

```
for (int i = 0; objectArray.Length()>i; i++) {
    objectArray[i].doStuff();
}
```

Maybe you have to use a different method for the length of the Array e.g. `size()`...